# Gatling Feeder - get info from a list

Tags: scala, performance, logic, gatling

I want to create new Gatling feeder on a list[Strings] from the memory.

In the scenario, I am executing this:

> ```
>            **.feed(GetGroupIdFeeder.getGroupIdFeed)**
> ```

My feeder looks like that:

> val getGroupIdFeed : Iterator[Map[String, List[String]]] = {
> Iterator.continually(Map("groups" -> myList))   }

My list look like that:  **my_List["a" , "b" , "c"]**

in results I am getting :

> **myList["a" , "b" , "c"]** as expected from the feeder...

**My expectations is to get from the feeder only "a"**

I am aiming that my feeder will be configured as circular.

### Details of what I want:

when calling the feeder:

- On 1st call, I get "a"
- on 2nd I get "b"
- on 3rd "c" and
- on 4th I get "a" again (circular)

How that can be done?

Any help in this regard would be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```scala
val getGroupIdFeed = Iterator.continually(List("a", "b", "c"))
  .flatten
  .map(value => Map("groups" -> value))
```

Comment: Thanks Stéphane LANDELLE

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneLANDELLE it saved my day